# want to add view in flip view dynamically at particular position and want to access it

Tags: android

i am creating an image Viewer for display image with next and previous option.
so adding imageview in flipview dynamically.

when picture select for display in image Viewer can be at any position in that picture folder so when i add it in flipper it is on first position but when i want to go previous It should display previous image according to that folder but problem is that how i add this in flipper.

i trying this by adding the image in flipper by flip.addviewAt(pos) here pos is position of file in that picture folder. 
but it not displaying the image. how i access it.

plz help how can i done this task .

Here is the code:

```
   public void PreImg()
{

    filePos--;                                                         
    mZoomView.setImage(mUrls);  

    View t=viewFlipper.getChildAt(filePos);
    if(t==null)
         viewFlipper.addView(mZoomView,filePos);    
    viewFlipper.showPrevious();     
}


public void NextImg()
{

    filePos++;      
    mZoomView.setImage(mUrls);

    View t=viewFlipper.getChildAt(filePos);
    if(t==null)
         viewFlipper.addView(mZoomView,filePos);    
        viewFlipper.showNext();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the View, make sure you call `invalidate()` *before* calling `showNext()`